# How to apply laravel 5 oldest() function on eager loaded model?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to apply oldest() function on eager loaded model

```
$model1 = Model1::where('id', $id)->with('model2')->oldest('model2.column')->first();
```

Here you can see that i want to apply oldest() function on column of eager loaded model that is model2.

How can i do this ? Or is there any other way around ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery in your `with` method. See [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

```
->with(['model2' => function($query) {
    $query->oldest('column');
}])
```

Comment: one more problem, i actually have nested eager loading like this: ->with('model2.model3:id,name') so its showing error

Comment: ok solved it like this: $query->oldest('column')->with('model3:id,name');